# AttributeError: __aexit__ al obtener la IP usando asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Estoy usando el módulo [`websockets`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#) para justamente eso, comunicar un código *JavaScript* con mi servidor web.

En la documentación del módulo se muestra un ejemplo simple, que **funciona** correctamente (se queda esperando a que se realicen conexiones, sin terminar):

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo( websocket, path ):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send( message )

async def main( ):
    async with websockets.serve( echo, "localhost", 8765 ):
        await asyncio.Future( )  # run forever

asyncio.run( main( ) )
```

En mi caso concreto, necesito que el puerto sea establecido por el Sistema Operativo; y necesito saber cual es. Para ello, he modificado el código del ejemplo:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def echo( websocket, path ):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send( message )

class Server:
    async def run( self ):
        server = await websockets.serve( echo, "localhost", None ) # OS-provided port
        port = server.sockets[0].getsockname( )[1]
        print( 'Puerto:', port )

        async with server:
            await asyncio.Future( )  # run forever

server = Server( )
asyncio.run( server.run( ) )
```

Así puedo obtener correctamente el puerto. Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo, obtengo el error del títullo:

> Puerto: 34377
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "question.py", line 21, in 
> asyncio.run( server.run( ) )
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
> return loop.run_until_complete(main)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()
> File "question.py", line 17, in run
> async with server:
> AttributeError: __aexit__

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Comment: Creo que ese `with server` no va, si quieres establecer un contexto deberías hacerlo así `async with websockets.serve( echo, "localhost", None ): awair asyncio.Future()`

Comment: Tengo un `async with server:`. No puedo hacerlo como dices (que es como estaba en el ejemplo de `websockets`) porque necesito acceder a diversos datos del socket servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato correcto es:

```
class Server:
    async def run( self ):
        async with websockets.serve( echo, "localhost", None ) as server:
            port = server.sockets[0].getsockname( )[1]
            print( 'Puerto:', port )

            await asyncio.Future( )  # run forever
```

El `with` es equivalente a un `open` con un `close` automático al salir del bloque. Eso que abres se específica con `as`:

```
with something as nombre:
```

El `something` es un *context manager*; un objeto que tiene definido los métodos mágicos `__enter__` y `__exit__`, los que se ejecutan al entrar y al salir de bloque respectivamente.